# What do Amiibo do in Codename S.T.E.A.M.?

Tags: amiibo, code-name-steam

I read that Codename S.T.E.A.M. supports Amiibo. What do the Amiibo do, and are all Amiibo compatible or only a select few?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Tap any Fire Emblem™ character from the Super Smash Bros.™ series of amiibo to the New Nintendo 3DS™ XL system to add them to your team and play as them in battle!
- Each character adds a new dimension to gameplay by wielding weaponry pulled straight from the Fire Emblem series—like Marth’s sacred sword, the Falchion, or Ike’s blessed blade, Ragnell.
- If they fall in battle, amiibo characters must be tapped again in order to add them back to your team.
- Compatible with the following amiibo figures: Marth, Ike, Robin, Lucina

[Source](http://www.nintendo.com/amiibo/games/detail/JqkGN0p5yPN-mzaWdc2kpJPUIDcSA7NI)